# Opera 10, jquery with regex replace

Tags: jquery, regex, opera

I have a jquery plugin that is working on all browsers, except opera. The removeHighlight function gets triggered, but the html is not changed. As far as I can see IE, FF, Chrome and Safari work as expected.

My example can be found here:
http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/plugin-dev/

The plugin's url is:
http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/plugin-dev/jquery.highlight.js

Basically, I just want to remove all span tags with a specific class, leaving the text as-is.

Can anyone explain why opera is responding differently, and provide a solution or work-around ?

Thanks.

Comment: Demo URL is now http://www.pritaeas.net/public/jquery/hp/highlight/live-demo.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is in your `removeHighlight` function, in regex. I don't know why, but your regex doesn't work if it is in form:

```
var source = new RegExp("<span class=.?" + options["cssClass"] + ".?>(.*?)</span>", "ig");
```

especially first `.?` is problematic in this case. When you change it to `.` or `\"`, then your regex works great. You can use `\"` form, as in correctly formatted html all attributes should be enclosed in parenthesis, and you can add them in `highlight` function too:

```
var target = "<span class=\"" + options["cssClass"] + "\">%&</span>";
```

Comment: I tried that, but in IE apparantly jQuery does not add the quotes. So I decided for no/one character before and after. For what reason would .? be problematic ?

Comment: I think \"? does the trick. Still. Can anyone tell me why the .? is ineffective here ?

Comment: I think it's a bug, I submited it to Opera and we'll see what they will say about it'

Comment: Thanks MBO, found the bug report (for the record it's now tracked as CORE-26329) and will push it towards a fix.